# Differences between Stack[] and mutable.Stack[]()

Tags: scala, scalatest

If I import `collection.mutable.Stack` should I use `Stack[]` or `mutable.Stack[]()` and are there any differences between the two?

Comment: Have you tried it? References to `mutable.Stack` will only work if you `import collection.mutable`. (BTW, `Stack` is deprecated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do both at the same time. There are 2 possible ways.

1.
Importing `scala.collection.mutable.stack`

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Stack
val stack: Stack[Int] = new Stack[Int]
```

2.
Importing `scala.collection.mutable`

```
import scala.collection.mutable
val stack: mutable.Stack[Int] = new mutable.Stack[Int]
```

In the first example you are importing `scala.collecion.mutable.Stack`. Therefore you can directly use `Stack` object and its functions. In the second one, you are importing `scala.collection.mutable`. This way you are eligible to use `mutable` package's functions. You have to use objects in this package by calling `mutable.xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

If you in general follow the functional principle to use immutable data structures as much as possible, I would `import scala.collection.mutable` and use `mutable.Stack` to make it clear that you are using the mutable version in this particular case.
This convention is also described in the [scala documentation for collections](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html)